# Http connection error while starting up R studio

Tags: r, rstudio, startup, httpconnection, macos-monterey

I was using RStudio 2023.03.0+386 . I was using metaboanalystR and pathview package on R for data analysis. Meanwhile, I wanted to change the working directory - and that's when it showed an error. Below is the error that I encountered for the first time.

ERROR ENCOUNTERED FOR THE FIRST TIME

R Session Startup Failure Report

RStudio Version

RStudio 2023.03.0+386 "Cherry Blossom " (3c53477, 2023-03-09) for macOS

Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) RStudio/2023.03.0+386 Chrome/108.0.5359.179 Electron/22.0.3 Safari/537.36

Error message

[No error available]

Process Output

The R session exited with code 1.

Error output:

[No errors emitted]
Standard output:

[No output emitted]
Logs

```
/Users/ABC/.local/share/rstudio/log/rsession-ABC.log

2023-06-22T06:11:34.704389Z [rsession-ABC] WARNING Abort requested; LOGGED FROM: bool rstudio::session::connection::checkForAbort(boost::shared_ptr<HttpConnection>, const boost::function<void ()>) src/cpp/session/http/SessionHttpConnectionUtils.cpp:135
2023-06-22T06:11:34.704389Z [rsession-ABC] WARNING Abort requested; LOGGED FROM: bool rstudio::session::connection::checkForAbort(boost::shared_ptr<HttpConnection>, const boost::function<void ()>) src/cpp/session/http/SessionHttpConnectionUtils.cpp:135
```

Also, my R works fine and I can do some mathematics in R terminal as well. As far as I know there are no startup customizations.

Much Appreciate the help!

I tried uninstalling and installing R studio multiple times, installed different versions of R studio, deleted local R studio folder, and  re-installed macOS operating system. None of these worked.